# How does recursion break out of the first recursive quick sort call?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, quicksort

What signals the program to say, "Ok the first recursive quickSort call is done; proceed to the second recursive call"?

```
int partition (int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = arr[high];    // pivot
    int i = (low - 1);  // Index of smaller element

    for (int j = low; j <= high- 1; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] <= pivot)
        {
            i++;    // increment index of smaller element
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);
    return (i + 1);
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high);
        quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1);
        quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual question roots to the [Recursion Stack](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-a-stack-used-to-perform-recursion).

Let's first understand [Recursion](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/recursion/explanation-of-recursion/), which basically constitutes a method that keeps calling itself on increasingly smaller cases and repeats the same non recursive procedure each time until it reaches base case, at which is stops.

In the case of [QuickSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), the base case of the recursion are lists of size zero or one, which never need to be sorted. If this is not the case, the array not meant to be sorted. That's why we call the QuickSort method again, twice, on arrays of smaller sizes.

We recurse on the side of the array containing all the elements from `A[0] to A[i - 2]`, and the side of array containing the elements `A[i] to A[A.length - 1]`.

Why do we leave out `A[i - 1]`? Simple - It's already in its correct place.

Comment: Ok. I am understanding it like this: once you reach the point where another recursive call is not made, then it returns execution to the **original** calling function. And so since it is in the original caller, it then proceeds past the first quickSort recursive call and onto the second. Is that correct?

Comment: @AllenEricsson Yes. That a call happens to be recursive doesn't really matter since it works the same way as with two `printf` statements. When the first call is finished the second is called. This happens in all the depths but that is irrelevant for one of the iterations.

Comment: So what then happens to the other stack frames? Say there are five recursive calls and the fifth call is when low >= high. What then happens to the other four frames?

Comment: @John: That's exactly where Stack used, to store the reference to that particular thread!